# How do I know if a regular for is a postback in ASP.ENT (was Why is IsPostback not set in ASP.NET plain forms)

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, webforms

I am using ASP.NET to process plain forms, posting back to myself.
(I dont want to use ASP.NET forms, with runat="server )

To IsPostBack is not set when it really has to be a postback.

What is the reason for this?

Should I not post back to myself?

```
<form method="post" id="theForm" action="http://localhost/index.aspx">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  <input ID="titleTB" type="text" />
  <input id="zipTB" type="text" /><br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use runat="server", you can always use other methods such as Request.HttpMethod, which will be set to "POST" when using postbacks.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to set the runat='server' attribute for postbacks to work correctly for your form and controls.

Actually Olav, if you really want absolute control over the HTML and its processing i suggest you take a look at [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) that was designed with this in mind

Comment: I am using (and want to use) plain forms, not ASP.NET forms!  The ASP.NET code should "know" if it is a postback or not even if it is not an ASP.NET web form.

Comment: Unforunately Olav, ASP.NET requires some additional plumbing to support the webforms model. The only way this additional data will be sent to the webserver for processing as far as I know is if you set this attribute

Comment: Add the runat attribute, turn off ViewState and EventValidation. It's as close as it gets. IsPostback is a server-side feature, you don't want to use a server-side form, so you can't use server-side features, either. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Like Conrad said... you can't have the goods of both worlds. IsPostback is part of WebForms functionality, and webforms comes together with the runat="server" tag, (and some viewstate, eventvalidation tag, long dom id's :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Something like
'POST' = Request.HTTPMETHOD

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can't use IsPostback without having the asp.net goodness on your page, you might be able to look at the http header variable REFERRER - this tells you where the request came from - if it's your page then it was *probably* a postback...